# How to draw a curve with just CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create the same header that attached below this post with the **only CSS**, Do you have any solution?
I've used elliptical border radius but it was not like the picture that i want.
[image: border radius like this picture]

```css
body{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
*{
  margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 outline: 0;
 border: none;
}

.header{
  background-color: #3654cd;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 200px;
 border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
</div>
```

Comment: This is too broad of a question for Stack Overflow

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of what you've tried, otherwise this is a work order rather than a question.

Comment: @zzzzBov added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do it using `border-bottom` radius. Like this:

```css
div{
    background-color:blue;
    width:500px;
    height:90px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I could find was to make two classes. The first would be the header text, and the second would be a rounded div (or an ellipse) which will overlap and make it rounded at the bottom.

```css
.header,
.round {
  background: #00f;
  width: 100%;
}

.round {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  &nbsp;
</div>
<div class="round">
  &nbsp;
</div>
```